# 16.04 doesn't show up in boot menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04

I planned to Install 16.04 alongside 14.04 while sharing the same partition for home (not the same user names, though).

I've booted 16.04 from an USB key, chose the option "something else" in the installer, made a new partition for the new LTS, and set the boot loader there. The installation went without problems, but upon reboot, the GRUB menu only showed one Ubuntu item which booted into 14.04.

The new installation is available as a seperate disk in the dash, and I can mount it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common when installing more than one copy of linux.
Boot into any available version of linux and:

> sudo update-grub

This will rebuild the grub menu with all OSs.